# MS KB311765 and DsoFramer are missing from MS site

Tags: dsoframer

I tried to get DsoFramer and found that its [download page](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=ce2ca4fd-2169-4fac-82af-770aa9b60d77) and [KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311765) are missing. I've downloaded DsoFramer from cnet.com but I am still curious: why it is removed and if it is deliberate, what should we use instead of it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is normally because Microsoft called back the KB article. Either the product that it applies to is out of support, or the code in it encourages using of undocumented behavior, or the code does not follow new security guidelines.

My guess is that it relies on too many undocumented internal behavior of Office thus programs using it may break when Microsoft release a new Office version or a new service pack of existing Office versions.

Answer (score 5):

You can find the sample here - but be warned - there are alot of known problems with the DsoFramer.

http://download.cnet.com/Microsoft-Developer-Support-Office-Framer-Control-Sample-KB-311765/3000-2206_4-10732960.html

Answer (score 0):

> What should we use instead of DSOFramer control if it is discontinued by Microsoft?

I had a issue with Excel embedded in the DSOFramer control for which I called up the MSDN Support guys. The first thing he said was that DSOFramer should not be used in application as it have many known problems and Microsoft has discontinued it and removed it from the site.