# DSOFramer.ocx Hosting word documents in 64 bit Windows Forms

Tags: 64-bit, ms-word, add-in, dsoframer

It looks like the DSOFramer.ocx component is not available for download anymore from MSDN as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1439168/ms-kb311765-and-dsoframer-are-missing-from-ms-site). Also the DSOFramer component is a 32 bit component. Given this, i have 2 questions:

1. Is there any other alternative for hosting a word document in a Windows Form apart from using the DSOFramer.ocx component?
2. If i move to Windows 64 bit operating system, and run the windows form as a native 64 bit process, then how do I host the word document in a 64 bit process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you compile your application as a 32 bit app, Dsoframer will continue working for you.
Go to your Project Properties under Build tab and set Platform Target to x86.