# Embed third party exe in my Form?

Tags: c#

Is this possible? Like embedding the actual .exe in your program, for example embedding notepad in it, preferably also without the border.

Comment: in theory yes... but it depends on several aspects... so you need to give more details... what have you tried ? what is the specific goal ? Any error messages/ exceptions ?

Comment: why would you want to do this?

Comment: Do you mean you want to only have one exe in your program folder, or do you just mean that you want to launch a program, putting it within your program?

Answer (score 3):

#### For [winforms](/questions/tagged/winforms)

Take a look at this code project. It contains code for a control that allows you to host processes within it.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/AppControl.aspx

> Though not a common task, recently I needed to take an existing
> executable application and embed it into an application I was
> building. Oddly enough, I did not need any interaction between my
> application and the existing EXE. As it ends up, this is not a
> difficult thing to do. To make it even easier, I created a custom C#
> control that allows you to specify the name of an executable you want
> embedded into your application. The control takes care of all the
> rest.

---

#### For [wpf](/questions/tagged/wpf)

[Hosting external app in WPF window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5028598/hosting-external-app-in-wpf-window)

Comment: Do you know about **WPF** equivalent for this **WinForms** wonderful thing?

Comment: Maybe this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5028598/hosting-external-app-in-wpf-window

Comment: Awesome! It fits me needs exactly. I'm so happy I've seen this answer accidently.

Comment: Did didn't help me, I tried this before asking the question, and it didn't work.

Comment: @user1011484: In the link you have downloadable example. Have you downloaded it? Where is the problem?