# How to embed in an external program to WPF or .net winform program?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, win32-process

For example, embed in "calc.exe" to wpf window，Thanks.

Comment: If you need embed process on your app, you should check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5028598/hosting-external-app-in-wpf-window

Answer (score 4):

You could use the [Process.Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start.aspx) method:

```
Process.Start("calc.exe");
```

But you cannot *load the exe* into an existing WPF window.

Answer (score 4):

You don't. You can **start** another process by invoking it using [System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e8zac0ca%28v=vs.100%29), but you can't "import" a process.