# Host External Application in WPF TabControl

Tags: c#, wpf, hwndhost

I have managed to create an example project that uses HwndHost to host Notepad (*not what my real project will be embedding*) inside a C# WPF tab control. For this, many thanks goes to those who replied to [Hosting external app in WPF window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5028598/hosting-external-app-in-wpf-window) (*BTW there's no need for DwayneNeed*)

This example works beautifully until you click on the hosted instance of Notepad, and **then try to change tabs**. If you don't have any content in the new page you are navigating to, you have to click on your current page selector first before it will accept a click on the other tab. If you have content on the other page (anything... just a button), then you are forced to click on the new tab selector TWICE to get it to navigate away.

**Things I have tried that didn't work:**

- Using [AttachThreadInput()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681956.aspx) to join the input threads of both application windows.
- Calling `this.InvalidateVisual();` on the Tab Control mouse down event.

**What does the trick:**

- Programmatically changing the `TabControl.SelectedIndex` value to what I want when a button is pressed.

To get around this problem, I think I am just going to have to use buttons in the place of the Tab Selectors (making them invisible) and just change the pages programmatically. This isn't a big deal, but I would just like to know if anyone else has encountered this problem, and maybe has an explanation for it!

p.s. I'm kinda new to WPF and C#.

Comment: I know just the guy who can answer this.

Comment: Are you using the SetParent() method described in the other SO topic you linked?

Comment: Yes, I'm using SetParent() method.

Answer (score 0):

Your hosted notepad application is another window, so if focus is in notepad - first click on tab selector activates your WPF window and makes it focused, than second cick do what you want to do.