# How to attach my wpf window with calculator (Desktop application)?

Tags: .net, winapp

How to attach my WPF window with Calculator which is a Desktop application?

My requirement is to when i move WPF window, calculator application should come together and vice-versa.

Please guide me the correct way to achieve my objective.

Answer (score 2):

First, I would assume that you are using the standard Windows Calculator app started as:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("calc.exe");
```

// or, alternatively

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("calc");
```

If so, then you can achieve your goal by using Win32 DLL functions:

```
[DllImport("user32")]
private static extern bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hWndInsertAfter, int X, int Y, int cx, int cy, int uFlags)
```

as detailed in: [Hosting external app in WPF window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5028598/hosting-external-app-in-wpf-window)