# external App inside WPF (notepad.exe works but others don't)

Tags: c#, wpf, external

I followed the tutorial made on this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/5070001/3549929
and It worked fine for "notepad.exe", but when I try another app instead of notepad, it doesnt work, I see the app running in the background through task manager but it doesnt show in my WPF form.

How can I control it?

Comment: Did you also read the comments on that answer?

Comment: @Clemens you mean this answer? "The API is supported, but you're not supposed to play with other's applications, like changing its caption, frame and parent relationship. It could very well crash the target application." If that's so, is quite impossible for that app then right?, I mean, I can invoke it without any trouble, but can't load it into my wpf.

Comment: from the answer: *It's actually still supported by some apps (mostly Microsoft ones, as Microsoft was almost the only sponsor of OLE...)*

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair Then I suppose I can't do what I wanted to right?