# how to wrap another process with WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, process, wrapper

I have WPF application . and I want to wrap another process into my GUI , for example notepad. like this picture

https://pasteboard.co/Iz9t9pM.png

How can i do that ?

If I create a new process of notepad , so notepad GUI will open separately from my GUI

Comment: Have you looked at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5028598/hosting-external-app-in-wpf-window

Comment: You have to look at https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/5fbfaf25-97c0-4250-be18-1857e934db25/problem-with-host-an-external-application-in-wpf?forum=wpf

Comment: @TheGeneral , the problem with your link is even I found the handler of the new process (not null) some application works fine with this code , but another application not open into my GUI , they open separately