# Loading an excel application with a file opened inside a windows .NET client app

Tags: c#, .net, office-automation

How to load an Excel application inside an .NET Windows client application?

The excel application should be hosted in windows form just a like any windows user control.

The loaded excel application will open a excel file created already.

Thanks

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15760/How-to-Integrate-Excel-in-a-Windows-Form-Applicati

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft released the source code for a solution called the [DSOFramer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1439168/ms-kb311765-and-dsoframer-are-missing-from-ms-site) (though they have since removed the solution).  This solution works in some ways but introduces a lot of problems as well.  If you think you have the skill and the automation approach posted on Codeproject doesn't meet your minimum requirements, then give it a shot.  Our application is still utilizing the DSOFramer today, but it is really for integrated view only support.