# Embed Excel Files in Form

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, excel, spreadsheet

I remember that with the old VB6, users have the option of displaying Microsoft Excel spreadsheet/Microsoft Access files using some sort of display control. Does VB 2010 express edition have this option/inbuilt control as well? If so, what is it called and how would I go about installing/reference it?

I have tried looking for such an option/inbuilt control in vb 2010 express edition but I could not find it and am having trouble with it.

I would like to display a excel spreadsheet file on this form I am going to create.

Comment: Don't use the word `tool` else you will see your question getting closed in no time :) The term that you are looking for is `an inbuilt VB control`.

Comment: Did you try to add a webbrowser control and then display the Excel file in that? For example `WebBrowser1.Navigate("C:\MyFile.xlsx")`

Comment: I think you're looking for the `dsoFramer` control: this is no longer available / supported. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1439168/ms-kb311765-and-dsoframer-are-missing-from-ms-site

Comment: @TimWilliams: Yes DsoFramer has been discontinued. In fact I have covered about it in my [blog](http://www.siddharthrout.com/2012/07/02/embed-excel-documents-in-vb-net-application/)

Comment: @SiddharthRout - I miss the framer :-( Still, the component from your blog post looks interesting.

Answer (score -1):

Depending on what purpose you are wanting to see the files, I suggest using a data grid view and loading each sheet there.  Programmatically, do whatever and be able to instantly see the changes or check it before closing/saving, etc. This seems to help in the office to reduce the number of input errors.

Hope this helps,